# Admob ad policy

Tags: android, admob

I want to show ads in my application but on AdMob site, there is an option that say

> is your app on playstore

Currently, my app is not on play-store but it will be in the near future so what option should I pick while adding the ads in my app?

Comment: you can config this later and Now you can use demo adkey to check your admod.

Comment: thanks for response @DeepakRor, but i implemented test ads and they are working fine as they should be. But my question still remains there, if I create an ad where I choose (that my app is not on play store) but later if I upload it on play store won't it create any chaos

Comment: no chaos, you can edit your admod setting later.

Comment: @DeepakRor, thanks i didn't know about that, so once I create an ad unit I can change its settings later, thanks

Comment: While developing test your app with TEST UNIT IDs. Before the final Publish change it with your real AD UNIT IDs. And You can also edit the things in ADMob later.